# Publishing OSS library release to jcenter and maven-central

Tags: gradle, maven-central, gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter

I'd like to publish my OSS library to be available in both `jcenter` and `maven-central` repositories. I have 2 questions related with this topic:

1. Should I publish by my own to both repositories, or there is some automated sync between them, so will be enough to publish only to one of them? If there is a sync, which one is the primary source and which when is mirrored?
2. I'd like to perform publish automatically from gradle, using some gradle plugin. Is there any single plugin, being able to work with both repositories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. JCenter is a super-set of Maven-Central and it syncs automatically with the package published to Maven-Central, so essentially artifacts published to Maven-Central will be automatically synced and available in JCenter as well.
2. Gradle has two plugins supporting publishing to [several repositories types](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:repositories), including Maven-Central and JCenter: **(1)** A "legacy" [**maven** plugin](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html) and **(2)** a new incubating [**maven-publish** plugin](https://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).

Answer (score 4):

For sure you need to publish to only one, and another one should pick it up from there. The question is which one to select?

Although @amnon-shochot's solution works, I'd suggest much easier solution: doing it vice-versa and going with Bintray as a main distribution platform.

Publishing to Bintray is much easier than publishing to Maven Central, and Bintray supports [a very easy way to sync](http://blog.bintray.com/2014/02/11/bintray-as-pain-free-gateway-to-maven-central/) whatever you published to Bintray's JCenter to Maven Central.

Also, most of Gradle users already prefer `jcenter()` over `mavenCentral()` cause it's faster, more reliable, [gives you much more as a publisher](http://blog.bintray.com/2015/04/22/download-stats-and-logs-now-with-deep-user-insights/) and [more secure](http://blog.bintray.com/2014/08/04/feel-secure-with-ssl-think-again/).

You can publish to Bintray from Gradle using [Bintray Gradle plugin](https://github.com/bintray/gradle-bintray-plugin), which support verity of methods to specify what should be published (configurations, publications, filesets, etc.)

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: This is a useful answer, but you should disclose your affiliation with the product.

Comment: If you found this affiliation in 2 seconds, it means it is pretty much disclosed.

Comment: I'm an Artifactory/JFrog/JCenter user already and I recognize the name.

Comment: Good to know I am famous :) Seriously speaking, my profile states I am with JFrog, Artifactory and Bintray in numerous places. Spamming every answer with the same information doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Disclosures should be made *in your post* however. See the section on overt self-promotion in the [help/behavior] in this context.